# How to set the arraylist item to be add in to reverse order?

Tags: android, database, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget

In My Application, I am going to store name of all the available tables from my database with this code:

```
     public ArrayList<Object> showAllTable()
  {
      ArrayList<Object> tableList = new ArrayList<Object>();

      String SQL_GET_ALL_TABLES = "SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'";
      Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(SQL_GET_ALL_TABLES, null);
      cursor.moveToFirst();

      if (!cursor.isAfterLast()) 
      {
          do 
          {
              if(cursor.getString(0).equals("android_metadata"))
              {
                  //System.out.println("Get Metadata");
                  continue;
              }
              else
              {
                  tableList.add(cursor.getString(0));
              }
          }
          while (cursor.moveToNext());
      }
      cursor.close();

      return tableList;

  }
```

Yes i am able to store it. But while i am going to display it in to ListView, it will display in such way that last created shown at last. I want to display the list of the table as Last created, display first in to ListView.

Please help me, What should I have to do in my code to set such way of displaying tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to do it. The easiest is probably to change your SQL call by adding `ORDER BY`. Here's something you can try out:

**To order the items ascending:**

```
String SQL_GET_ALL_TABLES = "SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' ORDER BY name ASC";
```

**Or descending:**

```
String SQL_GET_ALL_TABLES = "SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' ORDER BY name DESC";
```

**Alternative solution**

Another option would be to do it like you're doing it right now, and instead go through the `Cursor` from the last to the first item. Here's some pseudo code:

```
if (cursor.moveToLast()) {
   while (cursor.moveToPrevious()) {
      // Add the Cursor data to your ArrayList
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

before return the values just call the method

```
Collections.reverse(tableList);
```

see the full code

```
public ArrayList<Object> showAllTable()

{ 
 ArrayList tableList = new ArrayList();

 String SQL_GET_ALL_TABLES = "SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'";
 Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(SQL_GET_ALL_TABLES, null);
 cursor.moveToFirst();

 if (!cursor.isAfterLast()) 
 {
  do 
  {
      if(cursor.getString(0).equals("android_metadata"))
      {
          //System.out.println("Get Metadata");
          continue;
      }
      else
      {
          tableList.add(cursor.getString(0));
      }
  }
  while (cursor.moveToNext());
 }
 cursor.close();
 Collections.reverse(tableList);
 return tableList;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. But Michell Bak's Answer works great. Thanks to you also.

Comment: most welcome dear.. but one small thing, if you use "SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' ORDER BY name ASC" ,this return the names in ascending order,not in the insertion order.For Example ,first i created the table named as 'tableone','tabletwo',tablethree' and 'tablefour'. the query returns the result as " 'tablefour','tableone','tablethree' and 'tabletwo'" So the result is not in the insertion order or reverse order. Please check it. and don't take negatively. just I am  explaining in detail.

Comment: Yes I know it. Thats why i am using the alternative Solution what is given by the  Michell Bak's in his answer. And it works as what i want.

Comment: Thanks for your Explaination.