# removing, restoring items in ListView and database

Tags: android, android-listview, sqlite

I have a `ListView` with items that are added dynamically.  When an item is added, it is added to the `ListView` and also inserted into a SQLite Database so that the items in  the list can be saved.  I can also remove specific items by getting the postion if the item and then removing it with that information.

This is how I **add** items (I use multiple classes):

In `DataModel.class`:

```
public void addItem(Object data) {

        String string = String.valueOf(data);

        mPlanetsList.add(createPlanet("planet", string)); 
        History history = new History();
        history.getDataHashMap().put("planet", data);
        history.addToHistoryDB();

        mHistoryList.add(history);

        if (null != mOnItemAddHandler) {
            mOnItemAddHandler.onItemAdded(data);
        }
    }
```

In `History`.class:

```
public void addToHistoryDB() {

        MySQLiteOpenHelper mDbHelper = MySQLiteOpenHelper.getInstance();
        SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = getContentValues();

        rawId = (int) db.insert(TABLE_NAME, COL_ID, values);
        db.close();
    }
```

This is how I **remove** items:

In `DataModel`.class:

```
public void removeItem(int index) { 

        if (mPlanetsList == null || index < 0 || index >= mPlanetsList.size()) {
            return;
        }
        // remove from mPlanetList
        mPlanetsList.remove(index);

        History history = mHistoryList.get(index);
        mHistoryList.remove(index);
        if (null != history) {
            history.remove();
            history = null;
        }

        // notify, the HistoryFragment will update view
        if (null != mOnItemAddHandler) {
            mOnItemAddHandler.onItemRemove(index);
        }
```

In `History`.class:

```
public void remove() {
        MySQLiteOpenHelper mDbHelper = MySQLiteOpenHelper.getInstance();
        SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        int r = db.delete(TABLE_NAME, "_id = ?",  // delete the int r ??
                new String[] { String.valueOf(rawId) }); 
        db.close();
    }
```

When the app in removed from the 'recent apps' or is restarted, `initList()` is called which restored the ListView items from the Database.

This is the code:

`DataModel`:

```
private void initList() {



        mHistoryList = History.getList();
        for (int i = 0; i < mHistoryList.size(); i++) {
            Object obj = mHistoryList.get(i).getDataHashMap().get("planet");
            mPlanetsList.add(createPlanet("planet", String.valueOf(obj))); 
        }
    }
```

`History`:

```
public static ArrayList<History> getList() {
        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
            MySQLiteOpenHelper mDbHelper = MySQLiteOpenHelper.getInstance();
            SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            String sql = "select * from " + History.TABLE_NAME;
            ArrayList<History> list = new ArrayList<History>();
            cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
            if (cursor != null) {
                for (cursor.moveToFirst(); !cursor.isAfterLast(); cursor
                        .moveToNext()) {
                    History item = new History();
                    item.fromCuror(cursor);
                    list.add(item);
                }
            }
            return list;
        } finally {
            if (null != cursor && Integer.parseInt(Build.VERSION.SDK) < 14) {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

This method works fine as long as the order of the list is not changed - I can add items and removes items and it all works perfectly.  However, I would like items to be added to the top of the list rather than the bottom.

So I read around on how to add items to the top of a ListView and found that by adding a 0 as the position when adding the item, the new items go to the top of the list.

```
mPlanetsList.add(0, createPlanet("planet", string)); // I put the 0 in wherever the item is added eg when adding from the database
```

When I do this, however, the items viewed/deleted in the ListView do not continue to correspond with the data in the Database.  For example, Lets say I add three items to the List: `dog` then `cat` then `horse`.  The ListView shows them in the correct order (`horse` at the top).  If I then delete an item, lets say: `cat` , the ListView updates and everyting is good. But if I then restart the app, `initList()` is called.  This is where the problem occurs - It is **not** `cat` that is removed from the list, it is `horse` or `dog`.

Possible points where I think the problem could be:

a) in the initList() - It is not adding the correct items

b) in the removeItem() - It is not removing the correct items from the Database.

c) in the getList() - maybe something with the cursor???

This think b) is more likely but I don't know where the problem is exactly or what to change it too.

**EDIT:**

After a little testing, I found that I was right that b) is where it goes wrong.

The steps to reproduce:

Create three items: `cat` then `dog` then `horse`. The `ListView` shows them in the correct order ie `horse` at the top, `cat` at the bottom. The `Database` shows them with `cat` at the top, `horse` at the bottom.

When I delete `horse` (top of `ListView`, bottom of `Database`) the `ListView` updates correctly, but in the Database it is not `horse` that has been deleted but in fact `cat`.

So because of the wrong removal, when the `Database` is used to restore the `ListView`, the ListView appears wrong.

I hope this makes things clearer!

**EDIT 2:** This is how I create my table:

```
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "history_table";
    public static final String COL_TITLE = "title";
    public static final String COL_CONTENT = "content";
    public static final String COL_DATE = "date";
    public static final String COL_TYPE = "type";
    public static final String COL_ONGOING = "ongoing";
    public static final String COL_DATA = "data";
    public static final String COL_ID = "_id";

    public static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table " + TABLE_NAME
            + "(" + COL_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + COL_TITLE
            + " text not null, " + COL_CONTENT + " text not null, " + COL_DATE
            + " text not null, " + COL_TYPE + " text not null, " + COL_ONGOING
            + " text not null, " + COL_DATA + " text not null  );";
```

This is getContentValues():

```
public ContentValues getContentValues() {

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(History.COL_TITLE, "MyTitle");
        values.put(History.COL_CONTENT, "MyContent");
        values.put(History.COL_DATE, "Date placeholder");
        values.put(History.COL_TYPE, "QuickNote");
        values.put(History.COL_ONGOING, "Ongoing placeholder");
        values.put(History.COL_DATA, new JSONObject(mDataHashMap).toString());

        return values;
    }
```

**EDIT 3:**

I have basically narrowed it down to the fact that because the order of items in the ListView and in the Database are different, deleting items by their postition in the list does not work.  So would a possible solution would be to invert the order of items in the database to match the ListView (good idea / possible ?).

**EDIT 3.1:**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7348117/2442638

This order by descending may help. I don't know where I should put it though

**EDIT 3.5:**

I now have the ordering working.  The deleting very nearly works, but there is now a problem that  the first deletion doesn't work. The rest work after that.  I am sorting by the `_id` and as that is `autoincrement` maybe it starts at 1 or 0 and the list starts at the other.  I will do more research

Comment: What type of adapter are you using? Also, related to you explanation: the removed cat reappears in the list? are the dog or horse still in the database? You should debug each operation in the scenario you described and see if the database is in the proper state.

Comment: @Luksprog `List<Map<String, String>> planetsList` This is what my list is when I supply in to the ListView. And the adapter is a `SimpleAdapter`  `SimpleAdapter simpleAdpt = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), planetsList,
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new String[] { "planet" },
    new int[] { android.R.id.text1 });`  I will try and find the state of the database at different stages

Comment: @Luksprog I was correct in my guess that b) was the problem. It is quite complicated to reproduce, but the removeItem() method removes the wrong item. I will add the the question the steps.

Comment: How's the `_id` column declared in your database? It's `AUTOINCREMENT`? How does the `getContentValues()` method look like?

Comment: @Luksprog Yes it is `autoincrement`. I have posted the `getContentValues() to the question

Comment: I can't see what's wrong. You should further debug the app especially to see what's happening to the ids. You should first insert the values in the database and see the ids and then print the ids the entire way, like before you delete the item, what rawId has the item thatwill be deleted(maybe you have static references so you get the wrong id etc), the items after the deletion etc.

Comment: The funny thing is that everything works when I don't put the items to the top of the list - Its just when I add the `0` that it starts to go wrong.  I will do some more testing. Thanks for your help

Comment: @Luksprog The order of items in the Database does not change when I add the `0`. So, because I remove items based on their position, removing from the `ListView` works but not from the DataBase. One solution would be to reverse the order of items in the Database, but I don't know if that is a good idea or even if it is possible.

Comment: How about something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7348117/2442638 I don't know where I can put though

Comment: *because I remove items based on their position,* - you shouldn't do this especially as you change positions. You'll use the position to delete it from the `ListView` but you need the id to delete it from the database, here's the problem. Don't inverse values in the database, you just need to make sure that each History object that you'll be deleting has the proper id from the database(which isn't happening in your code for some reason).

Comment: @Luksprog Thanks - I'll have a go at doing that

Comment: @Luksprog This will only work if once an _id (with columns) is deleted, the other rows don't "move up" to fill the gap. For example, lets say I have 3 rows.  If I delete row 2, row 3 shouldn't now become row 2 (taking the previous row 2's place) Does this "moving up" happen? For the method you suggested to work, once I have given a ListView item an _id, it should not change.

Comment: You're missing the point of what I said: As long as the `_id` column is set on `AUTOINCREMENT`, then the ids are guaranteed to be unique so the ordering of the list doesn't matter as a long as you have this id. The problem is that somewhere in your code the `rawId` variable which should point to that database _id gets replaced/offset which causes the wrong history object to be removed(as you use the rawId to delete the item from the database). The idea is that each History object should have a unique rawId which must point to the id from the database for that object.

Comment: I think I did understand I just didn't explain properly :-) But you managed to answer my question anyway!

Comment: Do you only want to add new items to the top of listview, and can be removed correctly?

Comment: @srain  I want to add items to the top, but then any item is then able to be delete (at the moment I do this via a dialog when an item is pressed). This allows me to delete from the listview with its position, but not from the database as I don't have its position there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two list in the app: `mHistoryList` and `mPlanetsList`, You should keep the order of the data itmes in them are the same.

You can add items to the top of `listview` by calling the method `addItem` in DataModel:

```
public void addItem(Object data) {

    History history = new History();
    history.getDataHashMap().put("planet", data);
    history.addToHistoryDB();

    mHistoryList.add(0, history);
    mPlanetsList.add(0, history.createPlanet());

    if (null != mOnItemAddHandler) {
        mOnItemAddHandler.onItemAdded(data);
    }
}
```

Then the new data will be at the top of the `listview`.

After app restart,  the code below will be called:

```
private void initList() {

    mHistoryList = History.getList();
    for (int i = 0; i < mHistoryList.size(); i++) {
        mPlanetsList.add(mHistoryList.get(i).createPlanet());
    }
}
```

We should make sure the data from `History.getList();` has the same order, in another word, the new data time in the head of the list.

So we should change the code to (`order by _id desc`):

```
public static ArrayList<History> getList() {
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        MySQLiteOpenHelper mDbHelper = MySQLiteOpenHelper.getInstance();
        SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        // order by _id desc
        String sql = "select * from " + History.TABLE_NAME + " order by _id desc";
        ArrayList<History> list = new ArrayList<History>();
        cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            for (cursor.moveToFirst(); !cursor.isAfterLast(); cursor.moveToNext()) {
                History item = new History();
                item.fromCuror(cursor);
                list.add(item);
            }
        }
        return list;
    } finally {
        if (null != cursor && Integer.parseInt(Build.VERSION.SDK) < 14) {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer srain. I had tried this earlier but I still had problems (please see my edit 3.5)  I will try again making sure my code looks like yours :-)

Comment: Does the code you send to me is the code you used? I saw it did not fetch the list by descending. If it was not the latest, would you paste the latest code. By the way, Have you built the project I sent to you? Did that act what you expect?

Comment: I removed the ordering from the code I sent you as Luksprog said is was not necessary. I will paste my version soon and try yours - I just haven't had time yet.

Comment: Thanks again srain! I just tested your code here - as I had already done the ordering, I just needed to add the `mHistoryList.add(0, history);`.  It works as hoped now :-)

Comment: @RiThBo congratulations!

Comment: Thanks :-) This is not really related to this question but if I want to add data to another column in my database do I need to create a new Hashmap and JSON object for each column?

Comment: I think you can put you all the data in a Hashmap. Then access the data by different keys.

Comment: Would you mind sending me a small example please? If I try to add to the current HashMap and then try to retrieve, it comes out null.

Comment: I sent a demo to you, check mail.